# How to express $\log_5 2$ in terms of a and b (Refer to qn)

Tags: logarithms, education

In my textbook, I came across this interesting question which I am currently struggling to solve:

If $\log_6 2 = a$ and $\log_5 3 = b$, express $\log_5 2$ in terms of a and b

The solution given is $\frac{ab}{1-a}$ but I do not know the working behind this. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, although I agree with the exponential approach, too!

**We're given**: $\log_6 2 = a$ and $\log_5 3 = b$

**We want**: $\log_5 2$

We must recall our logarithms rules. There are too many bases happening here, so let's fix that!

The change of base formula gives us $\log_6 2 = \frac{\log_5 2}{\log_5 6}$ -- I thought to do this because we're looking for all base 5. Interesting! It has what we're looking for, i.e. $\log_5 2$  !

Another rule from logarithms tells us: $\log_5 6=\log_5(2*3)=\log_5 2 + \log_5 3$. Aha! We see again our lovely longed for $\log_5 2$!!

Reviewing what we have: $a=\log_6 2 = \frac{\log_5 2}{\log_5 6}$ and $\log_5 6=\log_5 2 + \log_5 3$ $(=\log_5 2 + b)$

So, we have from the first part $a\log_5 6=\log_5 2$ -- we have a substitution from above we can do!

$a\log_5 6=\log_5 2$ => $a(\log_5 2 + b)=\log_5 2$. Distributing appeals to you. And factoring somewhere down the road.

Do you see how to arrive at the final solution?

Answer (score 2):

I find exponentials easier to deal with than logs.

The first log equation says that $2=6^a$, and the second says that $3=5^b$.

Rewrite $2=6^a$ as $2=2^a\cdot 3^a$, and then as $2=2^a(5^b)^a$. We obtain the equation
$$2=2^a\cdot 5^{ab}.$$
This can be rewritten as
$$2^{1-a}=5^{ab}.$$
Taking logs to the base $5$,we get $(1-a)\log_5 2=ab$. Since $a\ne 1$, the result follows.

Comment: Although I agree with switching to exponentials in some ways, I'm concerned with the final step where you divide by $1-a$. One should really justify more as to why we are guaranteed $a \neq 1$ (yes, it's of course true). I also kind of like forcing the usage of logarithm rules, as people aren't comfortable with them -- but that's my evil side.

Comment: @ZachHaney: I put in the $a\ne 1$ as a general warning about indiscriminate division. Someone wondering why $a\ne 1$ can look at $6^a=2$.